# Update with default values for non nullable fields

Tags: laravel

There is a field  in my table `sample`, which has a default, but this field won't accept `NULL` value.

When  i update my form, and if i leave those field empty

```
$model->update($request->all());
```

is returning an error

> Column 'sample' cannot be null (SQL: update `mytable` set `updated_at`
>   = 2018-04-28 11:13:46, `sample` = , `name`= 'test' where `id` = 1)

What's the best way to update model with default values for non filled fields?

Comment: If the field in the database can be null, why didn't you add a ->nullable(); clause to it? Isn't that why it's there for?

Answer (score 1):

You can filter $request array to get rid of empty input values with array filter function:

```
$model->update(array_filter($request->all()));
```

Comment: @user866933 If the answer is what you seeking for please mark it as best answer. In case other people can find the answer without any difficulty.

Comment: This also removes values like `false`, `0` and `"0"`.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir I answer this question depend on the need of the user. In this case its the right answer. maybe in some cases, your answer is better.

Answer (score 0):

I think you check first your  **sample** field get `null` then set default value.

```
if (empty($request->get('sample', null))) {
    $request->replace(['sample' => '-- Your default value --']);
}
```

Then,

```
$model->update($request->all());
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to remove the `null` values from your input:

```php
$input = array_filter($request->all(), function($value) {
    return !is_null($value);
});
$model->update($input);
```